# When I update a record gives the following error "Binary stream '0 'does not Contain a valid BinaryHeader"

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Question
{
```

this is the class

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Employee
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
```

this is method write record

```
public class Write
{
public void WriteRecord(Employee emp)
{
if (!File.Exists("records.dat"))
{
    FileStream savefile = new 
    FileStream("records.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,    FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(savefile, emp);
    savefile.Flush();
    savefile.Close();
    savefile.Dispose();
    formatter = null;
}
else
{
FileStream savefile = new 
FileStream("records.dat", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(savefile, emp);
savefile.Flush();
savefile.Close();
savefile.Dispose();
formatter = null;
}
}
```

this is method update

```
public void UpdateRecord(Employee employ,Int32 id)
{
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
long record = 0;
//      
FileStream readfile = new 
FileStream("records.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

while (record < readfile.Length)
{
record = readfile.Position;
readfile.Seek(record, SeekOrigin.Begin);
employ = (Employee)formatter.Deserialize(readfile);

if (employ.Id == id)
{
formatter.Serialize(readfile, employ);
readfile.Flush();
readfile.Close();
readfile.Dispose();
formatter = null;
return;
}                
}
}
```

when call this method go the error after update

```
public void ReadRecord()
{
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
long record = 0;
Employee emp = new Employee();
FileStream readfile = new 
FileStream("records.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
while (record < readfile.Length)
{
readfile.Seek(record, SeekOrigin.Begin);
emp = (Employee)formatter.Deserialize(readfile);

Console.WriteLine("Number: " + emp.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + emp.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + emp.LastName);
Console.WriteLine("=====================================");

record = readfile.Position;
}
readfile.Flush();
readfile.Close();
readfile.Dispose();
formatter = null;
}
```

this method return a record

```
public void GetRecord(ref Employee emp, int id)
{
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
long record = 0;
Employee emplea = new Employee();
FileStream readfile = new 
FileStream("records.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
while (record < readfile.Length)
{
readfile.Seek(record, SeekOrigin.Begin);
emplea = (Employee)formatter.Deserialize(readfile);
if (emplea.Id == id)
{
emp = emplea;
readfile.Flush();
readfile.Close();
readfile.Dispose();
formatter = null;
return;
}
record = readfile.Position;
}            

}
}
}
```

this is the mai class
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

```
namespace Question
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Employee exaple1 = new Employee();
exaple1.Id = 1;
exaple1.Name = "Juan";
exaple1.LastName = "Perez";
Write record = new Write();
record.WriteRecord(exaple1);

Employee exaple2= new Employee();
exaple2.Id = 2;
exaple2.Name = "Jose";
exaple2.LastName = "Medina";

record.WriteRecord(exaple2);

Employee exaple3 = new Employee();
exaple3.Id = 3;
exaple3.Name = "Marcos";
exaple3.LastName = "Paniagua";

record.WriteRecord(exaple3);

Employee exaple4 = new Employee();
exaple4.Id = 4;
exaple4.Name = "Nurys";
exaple4.LastName = "Santnaa";

Employee exaple5 = new Employee();
exaple4.Id = 5;
exaple4.Name = "Carlos";
exaple4.LastName = "Encarnacion";

record.WriteRecord(exaple5);

Console.WriteLine("Records Add");
Console.ReadKey();

exaple1.Id = 2;
exaple1.Name = "JUAN RAMON";
exaple1.LastName = "GOMEZ DIAZ";
record.UpdateRecord(exaple1, 2);

Console.WriteLine("Record Updated...");
Console.ReadKey();

record.ReadRecord();

Console.WriteLine("Record Reads...");
Console.ReadKey();

Employee emplea = new Employee();
record.GetRecord(ref emplea, 4);

Console.WriteLine("Number: " + emplea.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Number: " + emplea.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Number: " + emplea.LastName);
Console.WriteLine("Get Record");
Console.ReadKey();

}
}
}
```

Comment: Hard to read due to lack of indenting.

Comment: After changing the employee instance, the size of serialized employee record will not be the same as the original employee record. When you call the UpdateRecord, you overwrite the existing employee record and this could corrupt the file.

Comment: This cannot work.  You hope that ever record in the file is the same size.  They are not, the strings are the problem.  High time to consider a simple dbase engine, like SQL Compact.